# Google Maps JS API

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Using the Google Maps JS API, is there a way to detect if a user has changed the map type using the map type controls?

I have a small script to automatically change the map type to satellite when above a specific zoom level and then back again afterwards.  This is all great however it would be even better to just keep using the users preferred map type if they change it rather then me overiding them each time they cross the zoom level threshold.

This is NOT a duplicate of other questions as I need to find out when the map type is changed BY THE USER. Not by myself in a script. The current map type change event is fired for BOTH scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a flag to identify that

```
var userMapStyle,
    scriptTrigger = false;


google.maps.event.addListener(map, "maptypeid_changed", function() {
   var newMapType = map.getMapTypeId();
   if (!scriptTrigger){
      userMapStyle = newMapStyle;
   }
   scriptTrigger = false;
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "zoom_changed", function() {
    if(!userMapStyle){
      // change the map style according to your logic as user has not made a selection yet
    }
});
```

and then set `scriptTrigger` to `true` whenever your script automatically changes the map type (*right before making the call*)

Answer (score 0):

Google does not provide the way to access to the MapTypeControl.
In this case, create your MapTypeController by yourself.

Here is the simple example.
Changes the map type to hybrid automatically if zoom level becomes over 8.
But you can change the map type by your hand with the controller, and detect it.

https://jsfiddle.net/wf9a5m75/bbjd8Lth/17/

```
function CustomMapTypeControl(container, options) {
  google.maps.MVCObject.call(this);

  var self = this;
  self.setValues(options);

  var mapTypes = [
    {label: "ROADMAP", id: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP},
    {label: "HYBRID", id: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID}
  ];
  var buttons = mapTypes.map(function(mapType) {
    var button = document.createElement("div");
    button.style.float="left";
    button.style.minWidth="38px";
    button.style.fontSize='11px';
    button.style.padding="8px";
    button.style.background="white";
    button.style.color="black";
    button.style.textAlign="center";
    button.style.backgroundClip="padding-box";
    button.style.boxShadow="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.298039) 0px 1px 4px -1px";
    button.innerText = mapType.label;
    button.id = mapType.id;
    button.style.cursor = "pointer";
    return button;
  });

  buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(button, 'click', function() {
      var button = this;
      google.maps.event.trigger(self, 'click', button.id);
      self.set("mapTypeId", button.id);
    });
    container.appendChild(button);
  });

}

CustomMapTypeControl.prototype = new google.maps.MVCObject();


/**
 * Start from here (onLoad)
 */
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {
console.log("OK");
  var div = document.getElementById('map');
  var map = new google.maps.Map(div, {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeControl: false
  });
  var customMapTypeControlDiv = document.createElement("div");
  customMapTypeControlDiv.style.padding="10px";
  var customMapTypeControl = new CustomMapTypeControl(customMapTypeControlDiv, {
    map: map
  });

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(customMapTypeControlDiv);
  customMapTypeControl.bindTo("mapTypeId", map, "mapTypeId", false);

  customMapTypeControl.addListener("click", function(mapTypeId) {
    alert("user clicked = " + mapTypeId);
  });

  map.addListener("zoom_changed", onZoomChanged);
});

function onZoomChanged() {
  var map = this;
  var zoom = map.getZoom();
  if (zoom > 8) {
    map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID);
  } else {
    map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
  }
}
```

[image]